# SQL Sum and Group By for a running Tally?

Tags: group-by, sum, sql-server-express

I'm completely rewriting my question to simplify it.  Sorry if you read the prior version.   (The previous version of this question included a very complex query example that created a distraction from what I really need.)  I'm using SQL Express.

I have a table of lessons.

```
LessonID  StudentID  StudentName  LengthInMinutes
1         1          Chuck        120
2         2          George       60
3         2          George       30
4         1          Chuck        60
5         1          Chuck        10
```

These would be ordered by date.  (Of course the actual table is thousands of records with dates and other lesson-related data but this is a simplification.)

I need to query this table such that I get all rows (or a subset of rows by a date range or by student), but I need my query to add a new column we might call PriorLessonMinutes.  That is, the sum of all minutes of all lessons for the same student in lessons of PRIOR dates only.

So the query would return:

```
LessonID  StudentID  StudentName  LengthInMinutes PriorLessonMinutes
1         1          Chuck        120             0
2         2          George       60              0
3         2          George       30              60 (The sum Length from row 2 only)
4         1          Chuck        60              120 (The sum Length from row 1 only)
5         1          Chuck        10              180 (The sum of Length from rows 1 and 4)
```

In essence, I need a running tally of the sum of prior lesson minutes for each student.  Ideally the tally shouldn't include the current row, but if it does, no big deal as I can do subtraction in the code that receives the query.

Further, (and this is important) if I retrieve only a subset of records, (for example by a date range) PriorLessonMinutes must be a sum that considers rows that are NOT returned.

My first idea was to use SUM() and to GROUP BY Student, but that isn't right because unless I'm mistaken it would include a sum of minutes for all rows for each student, including rows that come after the row which aren't relevant to the sum I need.

OPTIONS I'M REJECTING:  I could scan through all rows in my code that receives it, (although this would force me to retrieve all rows unnecessarily) but that's obviously inefficient.  I could also put a real data field in there and populate it, but this too presents problems when other records are deleted or altered.

I have no idea how to write such a query together.  Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great opportunity to use Windowed Aggregates. The trick is that you need SQL Server **2012** Express. If you can get it, then this is the query you are looking for:

```
select *,
  sum(LengthInMinutes) 
    over (partition by StudentId order by LessonId 
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
    as PriorLessonMinutes 
from Lessons
```

Note that it returns NULLs instead of 0s (zeroes). If you insist on zeroes, use COALESCE function to turn NULLs into zeroes.

I suggest using a nested query to limit the number of rows returned:

```
select * from
(
  select *,
    sum(LengthInMinutes) 
      over (partition by StudentId order by LessonId 
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
      as PriorLessonMinutes 
  from Lessons 
) as NestedLessons
where LessonId > 3 -- this is an example of a filter
```

This way the filter is applied after the aggregation is complete.

Now, if you want to apply a filter that doesn't affect the aggregation (like only querying data for a certain student), you should apply the filter to the inner query, as pruning the rows that don't affect the computation early (like data for other students) will improve the performance.

Comment: Very interesting.  So far it's an upvote, and I may click the check for Answer later if I can make it work.  (I don't currently have SQL Server 2012 Express it's only a release candidate which concerns me.)  Also I'm not familiar with this syntax, so before I upgrade I'd like to ask a question: Would the "unbound preceding" cause it to do a sum of all rows including those that are NOT returned?  See my paragraph beginning with: "Further, (and this is important)..."  That caveat may be the sticking point.

Comment: Launch event for SQL Server 2012 is scheduled for March the 7th. Final bits of SQL Server 2012 Express should be available around that time. See http://sqlserverlaunch.com/WW/Home .

Answer (score 0):

I feel the following code will serve your purpose.Check it:-

```
    select Students.StudentID ,Students.First, Students.Last,sum(Lessons.LengthInMinutes)    
    as TotalPriorMinutes from lessons,students
    where Lessons.StartDateTime < getdate() 
    and Lessons.StudentID = Students.StudentID 
    and StartDateTime >= '20090130 00:00:00' and StartDateTime < '20790101 00:00:00'
    group by Students.StudentID ,Students.First, Students.Last
```

Comment: I haven't checked it yet but please note that while you were typing your answer, I completely rewrote my question.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Well, I've checked it now.  Of course it kinda refers to my question as originally written, which had the join in it, not what's now shown above.  (I can handle the join issue.)  And it includes GetDate which is the current date which isn't relevant as each lesson has its own date field so the same query should yield the same results regardless of when it is executed.  Thank you though.

Comment: Sukanya, I removed the code from your answer because it was really addressing an issue that wasn't what my question was about.  My fault, as I should have written my question more clearly in the first place.  The edited version of my question is much more pertinent.