# How to perform running sum (balance) in SQL

Tags: sql, accounting

I have 2 SQL Tables

unit_transaction 
unit_detail_transactions

(tables schema here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3204/2 )

[image: Here is the tables and the sample data on them]

What I need is to perform an SQL Query in order to generate a table with balances. Right now I have this SQL Query but it's not working fine because when I have 2 transactions with the same date then the balance is not calculated correctly.

```
SELECT 
ft.transactionid,
ft.date,
ft.reference,
ft.transactiontype,
CASE ftd.isdebit WHEN 1 THEN MAX(ftd.debitaccountid) ELSE MAX(ftd.creditaccountid) END as financialaccountname,
CAST(COUNT(0) as tinyint) as totaldetailrecords,
ftd.isdebit,
SUM(ftd.amount) as amount,
balance.amount as balance
FROM unit_transaction_details ftd
JOIN unit_transactions ft ON ft.transactionid = ftd.transactionid
JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    a.transactionid,
    SUM(CASE b.isdebit WHEN 1 THEN b.amount ELSE -ABS(b.amount) END) as amount
    --SUM(b.debit-b.credit) as amount
    FROM unit_transaction_details a
    JOIN unit_transactions ft ON ft.transactionid = a.transactionid
    CROSS JOIN unit_transaction_details b
    JOIN unit_transactions ft2 ON ft2.transactionid = b.transactionid
    WHERE (ft2.date <= ft.date)
    AND ft.unitid = 1
    AND ft2.unitid = 1
    AND a.masterentity = 'CONDO-A'
    GROUP BY a.transactionid,a.amount

) balance ON balance.transactionid = ft.transactionid

WHERE 
ft.unitid = 1
AND ftd.isactive = 1
GROUP BY 
ft.transactionid,
ft.date,
ft.reference,
ft.transactiontype,
ftd.isdebit,
balance.amount
ORDER BY ft.date DESC
```

The result of the query is this:

[image: SQL Query Result]

Any clue on how to perform a correct SQL that will show me the right balances ordered by transaction date in descendant mode?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: THINK OF 2 POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS

The problem is generated when you have the same date in 2 transactions, so here is what Im going to do:

1. Save Date and Time into "date" column. That way there won't be 2 exact dates.

OR

2. Create a "priority" column and set the priority for each record. So if I found that the date already exists and it has priority = 1 then the current priority will be 2.

What do you think?

Comment: I would encourage you to do some research on this. It's a common question, and many answers already exist on stack overflow.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing a CROSS JOIN (Cartesian product) to the transaction detail table in your subquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Sum and Group By for a running Tally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074625/sql-sum-and-group-by-for-a-running-tally)

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do a running sum.  I am going to show the syntax on a simpler table, to give you an idea.

Some databases (Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server 2012, Teradata, DB2 for instance) support cumulative sums directly.  For this you use the following function:

```
select sum(<val>) over (partition by <column> order by <ordering column>)
from t
```

This is a windows function that will calculate the running sum of  for each group of records identified by .  The order of the sum is .

Alas, many databases don't support this functionality, so you would need to do a self join to do this in a single SELECT query in the database:

```
select t.column, sum(tprev.<val>) as cumsum
from t left join
     t tprev
     where t.<column> = tprev.<column> and
           t.<ordering column> >= tprev.<ordering column>
group by t.column
```

There is also the possibility of creating another table and using a cursor to assign the cumulative sum, or of doing the sum at the application level.